# Python strings : Whole word match not working as intended

Tags: python, string, full-text-search

My objective is to search for presence of certain (whole) words in a string. Below is the code. I'm not able to understand why I'm getting a match for search word 'odin' as this isn't a whole word in my string. Can someone explain?. I expect no match to be found in this case.

```
import re
#search words
hero = ['catwoman', 'hellboy', 'eternals', 'elektra', 'hydra', 'iron-man', 'iron man', 'green arrow', 'nightwing', 'flash gordon', 'lanterne verte', 'lantern',
        'kryptonite', 'asgard', 'spider-man', 'spiderman', 'superheroes', 'super heroes', 'super hero', 'hancock', 'daredevil', 'avengers', 'metropolis',
        'gotham', 'batman', 'captain america', 'wolverine', 'magneto', 'dark knight', 'aquaman', 'shazam', 'wolverine', 'punisher', 'batmobile', 
        'daredevil', 'superwoman', 'supergirl', 'wonderwoman', 'batgirl', 'catgirl', 'starfire', 'sandman', 'superman', 'thor', 'x-men', 'x men',
        'marvel', 'spidey', 'superheroine', 'supervillain', 'supervillains', 'odin', 'loki', 'spiderman', 'ragnarok', 'asgardian', 'supergirl', 'spiderman', 
        'teen titans', 'stan lee', 'doctor strange', 'groot', 'ant man', 'ant-man', 'deadpool', 'professor x', 'wasp', 'phoenix', 'star wars',
        'eternals', 'morbius', 'shang-chi', 'shang', 'rocketeer']

#string
s = "Hoping to escape from his troubled past, former DEA agent Phil Broker (Jason Statham) moves to a seemingly quiet backwater town in the bayou with his daughter. However, he finds anything but quiet there, for the town is riddled with drugs and violence. When Gator Bodine (James Franco), a sociopathic druglord, puts the newcomer and his young daughter in harm's way, Broker is forced back into action to save her and their home. Based on a novel by Chuck Logan.^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) returns to action to save his daughter and his new town from a drug dealing sociopath (James Franco).^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) encounters trouble when he moves to a small town"

match = re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(hero)),s )

print(match)
```

Output

```
<re.Match object; span=(265, 269), match='odin'>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized what was going wrong. The search pattern did not have word boundaries for each word in "hero"
I changed the search pattern from `r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(hero))` to `r'\b{}\b'.format(r'\b|\b'.join(hero))` and now it is working as expected. Here is the full code :

```
import re
#search words
hero = ['catwoman', 'hellboy', 'eternals', 'elektra', 'hydra', 'iron-man', 'iron man', 'green arrow', 'nightwing', 'flash gordon', 'lanterne verte', 'lantern',
        'kryptonite', 'asgard', 'spider-man', 'spiderman', 'superheroes', 'super heroes', 'super hero', 'hancock', 'daredevil', 'avengers', 'metropolis',
        'gotham', 'batman', 'captain america', 'wolverine', 'magneto', 'dark knight', 'aquaman', 'shazam', 'wolverine', 'punisher', 'batmobile', 
        'daredevil', 'superwoman', 'supergirl', 'wonderwoman', 'batgirl', 'catgirl', 'starfire', 'sandman', 'superman', 'thor', 'x-men', 'x men',
        'marvel', 'spidey', 'superheroine', 'supervillain', 'supervillains', 'odin', 'loki', 'spiderman', 'ragnarok', 'asgardian', 'supergirl', 'spiderman', 
        'teen titans', 'stan lee', 'doctor strange', 'groot', 'ant man', 'ant-man', 'deadpool', 'professor x', 'wasp', 'phoenix', 'star wars',
        'eternals', 'morbius', 'shang-chi', 'shang', 'rocketeer']

#string
s = "Hoping to escape from his troubled past, former DEA agent Phil Broker (Jason Statham) moves to a seemingly quiet backwater town in the bayou with his daughter. However, he finds anything but quiet there, for the town is riddled with drugs and violence. When Gator Bodine (James Franco), a sociopathic druglord, puts the newcomer and his young daughter in harm's way, Broker is forced back into action to save her and their home. Based on a novel by Chuck Logan.^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) returns to action to save his daughter and his new town from a drug dealing sociopath (James Franco).^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) encounters trouble when he moves to a small town"

match = re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(r'\b|\b'.join(hero)),s )

print(match)
```

Output :

```
None
```

Answer (score 0):

re.search is pretty inacurate. It matches odin because in the sentence there's: " When Gator B>ODIN< (James F".
 How about a little simpler approach, with no regex?

```
import re
#search words
hero = ['catwoman', 'hellboy', 'eternals', 'elektra', 'hydra', 'iron-man', 
'iron man', 'green arrow', 'nightwing', 'flash gordon', 'lanterne verte', 
'lantern',
    'kryptonite', 'asgard', 'spider-man', 'spiderman', 'superheroes', 'super heroes', 'super hero', 'hancock', 'daredevil', 'avengers', 'metropolis',
    'gotham', 'batman', 'captain america', 'wolverine', 'magneto', 'dark knight', 'aquaman', 'shazam', 'wolverine', 'punisher', 'batmobile', 
    'daredevil', 'superwoman', 'supergirl', 'wonderwoman', 'batgirl', 'catgirl', 'starfire', 'sandman', 'superman', 'thor', 'x-men', 'x men',
    'marvel', 'spidey', 'superheroine', 'supervillain', 'supervillains', 'odin', 'loki', 'spiderman', 'ragnarok', 'asgardian', 'supergirl', 'spiderman', 
    'teen titans', 'stan lee', 'doctor strange', 'groot', 'ant man', 'ant-man', 'deadpool', 'professor x', 'wasp', 'phoenix', 'star wars',
    'eternals', 'morbius', 'shang-chi', 'shang', 'rocketeer']

#string
s = "Hoping to escape from his troubled past, former DEA agent Phil Broker 
(Jason Statham) moves to a seemingly quiet backwater town in the bayou with 
his daughter. However, he finds anything but quiet there, for the town is 
riddled with drugs and violence. When Gator Bodine (James Franco), a 
sociopathic druglord, puts the newcomer and his young daughter in harm's way, 
Broker is forced back into action to save her and their home. Based on a 
novel by Chuck Logan.^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) returns to action to 
save his daughter and his new town from a drug dealing sociopath (James 
Franco).^A former DEA agent (Jason Statham) encounters trouble when he moves 
to a small town"

split_sentence = s.split(" ")
for word in split_sentence:
if word in hero:
    print("{} is in hero list!".format(word))
```

Comment: thanks for responding, this could be another way to solve the problem, but I'm curious to know why the problem is only with the word 'odin' and no other. I'm infact using str.contains in my bigger code as string is actually a pandas series and I need to create another column that says match/no match

Comment: I guess only "odin" is contained in s string. If I understand problem correctly, that's the issue.